# Is there an easier way I can use this array of integers using a stack in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, stack

I have an array of integers and I want to push the entire array to a stack for example I have an array of integers made up of

```
 int[] myArrayInt = new int[10];
 Stack<int> myStack = new Stack<int>();

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        myArrayInt[i]=i;

 }

 myStack.Push(myArrayInt);
```

Now it won't let me do this because I have to push each individual integer of the array into the stack

```
 myStack.Push(myArrayInt[0]);
```

But I want my stack to look like this

```
 ---------------
 0123456789    bottom of stack
 ---------------
```

instead of

```
 9876543210  bottom of stack
 ---------------
```

I know I can just use a for loop to push all the integers of the array into the stack and then use another for loop when I pop from the stack and setting the for loop so that the integers go back into my array in the same order but I want to know if there was another way where I can avoid using for loops and with just one call of the pop function of the stack I get all the integers back into my array?

I'm learning depth-first-search algorithm and I'm using the stack to keep track of the current state my program is in.

Comment: For the latter you can use [`ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/415129w1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: see [Stack(ICollection) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ecsf21k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is no overload of `Push` that takes an `IEnumerable`, however there is a [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use `.Reverse` on your array and pass the result into the constructor to get the stack to look like `0123456789 <--Bottom`.

```
var myInts = new { 0, 1, 2, /*etc*/ };
var stack = new Stack<int>(myInts.Reverse());
```

To get it back out to an array, use the `ToArray` method:

```
var outInts = stack.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's kind of how I would approach this:

```
// Eliminate the for-loop to create your integer array
var intArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 9); 

// The constructor to Stack<T> takes an IEnumerable<T>
var myStack = new Stack<int>(intArray); 

... perform Stack operations

// To produce a T[] from what remains in the Stack<T>
var outIntArray = myStack.ToArray();
```

Now, since you aren't explaining what you're using the `Stack` for, it seems completely unnecessary here. You could simply replace all of this with `var outIntArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 9);` as musefan pointed out in the comments.

Comment: OP said *easy*... like: `var outIntArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 9);` and cut all that useless crap that does't even make for a sensible question

Comment: @musefan: I'm assuming OP is using the Stack for something, but when you say it like that... it makes you wonder.

Comment: I'm using the depth first search algorithm and I'm using the stack to keep track of the current state that my program is in